# SP13 - Finding all sites a group has access to

Tags: javascript, permissions, groups

In SharePoint 2013 when you're looking at a group's page (the one that lists all of the members of the group) you can open the 'settings' menu and there's a choice to 'view group permissions'. This will open a box that lists all sites, pages, files, etc... that the group has explicit access to (ie - not inherited) and what level of access the group has for each item. By viewing the source I can see that the menu is calling a JavaScript function. So... is there a way that I can programmatically do the same thing? My end state is to have a page where I can produce a list of groups, select one, and list all of the items that it has access to.

Comment: check this may help you https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a614e64d-4cf4-4d66-a2b2-56e532aa916b/how-to-programmatically-read-a-lists-groupspermissions?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Comment: looks good, but I need something client side, which is why I was looking into the possibility of a javascript answer.